# Passing parameter to SQL select statement IN clause acts weird.

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, tableadapter, query-builder

I've got the following query that returns 2 records (in DataSet's query builder)

```
SELECT        EmpID, Name, id
FROM          Users
WHERE        (CAST(id AS Varchar(20)) IN ('5688','5689'))
```

Now if I do the same query passing the parameter instead from code behind: String param = "'5688','5689'"; it returns null.

```
WHERE        (CAST(id AS Varchar(20)) IN (@param))
```

I tried taking off the very first and last ', but that did not make a diffrence.

!!!id is a unique PK!!!

Anyone's got a clue?

Comment: Could you please post the code that contains the specified parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found is quite simple, this works like a charm and there's no need for sps or other functions;

SQL:

```
SELECT whatever 
FROM whatever
WHERE (PATINDEX('%''' + CAST(id AS Varchar(20)) + '''%', @param) > 0)
```

C#:

```
String param = "'''1234'',''4567'''";
dataTable1 = tableAdapter1.getYourValues(param);
```

Comment: Here's a pretty comprehensive discussion on ways to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause/337792

Comment: This is just what I needed. My dataset designer kept defaulting my parameter to be `DbType = Object`, which the SQL didn't like so I had to update the parameter to be `DbType = String`, but then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

A variable is not allowed in the IN clause.
You are expecting the values as a comma delimited string you could use the split function (user defined and non-standard) to join them with the original tables:

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=326300&SiteID=1

For more information you can visit [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4ba1162d-fa76-452f-a59a-a6b1dc8e6d65/)

Answer (score 0):

`('5688','5689')` is an array of values.

Defining `String param = "'5688','5689'";` and using it as `(@param)` makes `('5688','5689')` a string. Which wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Bibhas is correct.  For me this worked:

`string param="'1234','4567'";` we can't use param as SQL Parameter(@param).

`command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE number IN (" + param + ")", connection);`

`command.ExcecuteReader();`

Comment: You append your values directly into SQL but we try to pass values by parameter. In my opinion your SQL can injectable.