# How to insert a string with ( ' ) in to the sql database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the strings which consists of ( ' ) quote mark like "mother's love" ...

While inserting the data by sql query from c#. It shows error. How can i rectify the problem and insert this kind of data successfully?

```
string str2 = "Insert into tblDesEmpOthDetails (EmpID, Interviewnotes) values ('" + EmpId + "','" + Interviewnotes + "')";
```

Interview notes consists the value like "Mother's love" (with single quote). While executing this query it shows error as "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')" how can i insert this type of strings?

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** -- *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language*, a language used by many database systems, but **not** a database product... We really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: @Killercam in this case, I think we can conclude that the OP is using concatenation to form queries, in which case the `'` to `''` trick is probably enough information to be dangerous. *Parameters* are the *correct* answer here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't use SQL parameters:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO table (text1, text2) VALUES (@text1, @text2)")) {

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text1", "mother's love");
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text2", "father's love");
    //...

    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your correct answer and also a valuable answer.

Comment: @Otiel: Will this code works:  `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codes", "'A','B','C'");`

Comment: @user1671639: (You should try it and ask a new question on SO if it does not work as you expect it) Yes, I don't see why it won't work.

Comment: @Otiel: Thanks.  I will post a question regarding this.

Comment: @Otiel: From this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374082/passing-parameter-to-sql-select-statement-in-clause-acts-weird/15503932#15503932) I found my answer.

Answer (score 14):

Use named parameters and the SqlParameter.

From http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string dogName = "Fido";  // The name we are trying to match.

        // Use preset string for connection and open it.
        string connectionString = 
            ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Description of SQL command:
            // 1. It selects all cells from rows matching the name.
            // 2. It uses LIKE operator because Name is a Text field.
            // 3. @Name must be added as a new SqlParameter.
            using (SqlCommand command = 
               new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dogs1 WHERE Name LIKE @Name", connection))
            {
                // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));

                // Read in the SELECT results.
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int weight = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    string name = reader.GetString(1);
                    string breed = reader.GetString(2);
                    Console.WriteLine("Weight = {0}, Name = {1}, Breed = {2}", weight, name, breed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Although, you could replace all ' characters in the string with two ' characters (''), it's not a good idea.  Because of this issue, and many other reasons (such as avoiding SQL-injection attacks), you definitely should be using named parameters rather than adding the values to your insert statement by concatenating them directly into the string.  For instance:

```
command.CommandText = "Insert into tblDesEmpOthDetails (EmpID, Interviewnotes) values (@EmpId, @Interviewnotes)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmpId", EmpId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Interviewnotes", Interviewnotes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to a string your trying to input

say you string was

```
string test = "that's not working correctly"
test = replace(Request.QueryString(test), "'", "''")
```

then test is now

```
"that''s not working correctly"
```

which is syntactically correct for SQL

Regards

Comment: This is technically workable, but is teaching a bad practice. The *correct* approach here is to use parameters. Anything else is simply dangerous.

Comment: While this address the author's problem I have to downvote for being a horrible idea.

Comment: Downvoted; while it solves this particular problem, it leaves open much larger ones.

Answer (score 2):

As a variant on the answers that (very correctly) point you at parameters: if this seems a lot of work, then *avoid it* with a tool such as [dapper](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper):

```
int empId = 123;
string notes = "abc";
connection.Execute(@"insert into tblDesEmpOthDetails (EmpID, Interviewnotes)
                     values (@empId, @notes)", new {empId, notes});
```

Dapper will automatically take the `empId` and `notes` (from the anonymous object) and add them as named/typed parameters. The similar `Query`/`Query<T>` extension-methods also allow for easy and highly-optimised *querying* directly into an object model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double ''

```
INSERT INTO something (Name) VALUES ('O''something''s')
```

This will insert O'something's.
Another example i read is:

Lets assume we have a string:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM name WHERE LastName='" & LastName & "' "
```

and if we have lastname something like O'Brian, O'Reily etc. we got string like

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE LastName='O'Brien'
```

the second ' will end the SQL statement. So the simplest solution here is to use double '' then we will have string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE LastName='O''Brien'
```

Comment: This is technically workable, but is teaching a bad practice. The *correct* approach here is to use parameters. Anything else is simply dangerous.

Comment: Yes, i hear about it. I just write this simple exam to explain double ''.

Comment: @JasonPaddle - If you go to the effort of making it clear this method should NOT be used and explain the CORRECT way to do it I will remove my downvote.